# How to convert a scapy packet into a raw packet

Tags: networking, endianness, scapy

I am using scapy as an extension of my application. after create a packet using scapy, I want to convert it into a raw packet which will be attached to my header.
Then the packet must be able to be sent through network directly.

```
myPacket.payload = Ether().toRaw()
```

So what I want to do is changing the host endian into network endian.
Is there a simple way to do so?

If `scapyPacket = Ether()/IP()/TCP()` is it possible that I could have one `scapyPacket.toRaw()` call such that all the fields are assembled into network endian accordingly?

Comment: it seems a packet.build() will do ....hope someone will provide some examples.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Answering the title question - scapy packet can be converted into bytes (as the ones being sent/received over network) using `str(packet)` or in scapy3k using `bytes(packet)`. Whether it is host/network byte order actually depends on the specific layer/protocol.